# Validating User String User Input

Tags: c++, string, c-strings

So I've been trying to create this program that will take up to 12 digits from the user using string and string classes.  The issue I'm having is:

1. Ignoring the (-) sign.
2. Ignoring the decimal point.
3. Giving an error when more than 12 digits are entered.
4. Only accepting digits (i.e no letters)

So far this is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

bool test(char [] , int);

int main()
{
const int SIZE= 13;
char number[SIZE];
int count;

cout<< "Please enter a number up to "<< (SIZE-1) <<" digits long." << endl;
cout<< "The number may be positive or negative" << endl;
cout<< "and may include fractions (up to two decimal positions)" << endl;
cout<< "Sign and decimal dot(.) are not included in the digit count:"<< "\t";

cin.getline (number, SIZE);

if (test(number, SIZE))
    {
    while (number[count]!='\0')
        {
        cout<< "The currency value is: \t $";
        cout<< setprecision(2) << number[count];
        count++;
        }
    }   
else
    {
        cout << "Invalid number: contains non-numeric digits.";
    }

return 0;
}



bool test(char testNum[], int size) 
{
int count;

for (count = 0; count< size; count++)
    {
        if(!isdigit(testNum[count]))
            return false;
    }

return true;    
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated, but the most important to me at the moment is the 4th point.  No matter what the input is, the output is "Invalid number:...." and I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: You even test the terminator (null char) with `isdigit()`. That said, why are you using a raw array at all? Use a `std::string line;` and then read that line with `getline(std::cin, line);` and start checks from there.

Comment: So, to not test the (null char) I put for( count <size-1 ) but I still receive the same output.

Comment: Consider how many characters you entered and how many you tested.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding.

Comment: @ElSpiffy You should stop the loop when the `'\0'` character is encountered.

Comment: Try every loop in your program, there aren't that many of them.

Comment: @ElSpiffy Would you mind if we improve the design of your program? It is improvable I think. Or is that an exercise or so?

Comment: How could it be improved? And no, it's a program I made up from scratch.

Comment: Learn a bit of `std::regex` in order to validate a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your test function always test 13 chars even if the input is shorter.

Instead pass a string and use the range based for-loop so that you only test the valid chars - something like:

```
bool test(string testNum) 
{
    for (auto c : testNum)
    {
        if(!isdigit(c))
            return false;
    }

    return true;    
}
```

Further you should change your main-loop (where you print the value) as well, i.e. use string instead of char-array.

BTW - notice that this will only check for digits. Your description of the valid input format will require a more complex test-function.

For instance to check for sign you could add:

```
bool test(string testNum) 
{
    bool signAllowed = true;
    for (auto c : testNum)
    {
        if (c == '-')
        {
            if (!signAllowed) return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(!isdigit(c)) return false;
        }

        // Sign not allowed any more
        signAllowed = false;
    }

    return true;    
}
```

But you still need more code to check for the dot (.)

If you don't want to use a range-based for loop, you can do:

```
bool test(string testNum) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < testNum.size(); i++)
    {
        if (testNum[i] == '-')
        {
            // Sign is only allowed as first char
            if (i != 0) return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(!isdigit(testNum[i])) return false;
        }
    }

    return true;    
}
```

Comment: Everything makes sense to me except the auto c, could you explain what that is? Are you using the auto keyword for c?

Comment: `auto` is just like a short hand for writing the type, i.e. the the compiler will automatically assign the correct type. In this case you could also write `for (char c : testNum)` because the range based for-loop on a string will return the chars in the string one-by-one.

Comment: `std::all_of` performs this same process

Comment: @StillLearning I created another Boolean to test if the argument is an element of the alphabet and for printable characters. I just don't know how to make a (-) sign an exception.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using the range based for loop?

Comment: @ElSpiffy - yes, you can do it without range based for loop. See update